# Phonegap: Source URL is not in Whitelist

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get PhoneGap 2.4.0 FileTransfer working on Android 4.2.

I get a Logcat warning message saying:

```
The Source URL is not in white list: 'http://api.etc.com'
```

Inside my res/xml/cordova.xml I have

```
<access origin=".*" subdomains="true"/>
```

This is supposed to whitelist all URL's but no luck, I still get the same warning and FileTransfer error 3.

Any ideas? Can I check if cordova.xml is being parsed at all?

Edit: I'm using a CordovaWebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by using PhoneGap 1.9.0 instead of 2.4.0. The errors return when using later versions.

I also managed to get it working by not using CordovaWebView but by using PhoneGap build. But this isn't viable in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using DroidGap, you need:

```
Config.init(this);
```

In the `onCreate` of your activity. Otherwise, all whitelisting will fail. Just found this out after two hours of painful digging.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you change your XML to:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

This white-lists basically the entire internet.  If you only want to white-list your domain, use something more specific.  See details here: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

The "origin" attribute is now "uri".

Comment: really? I just checked the code and the Config class is still looking for "access->origin". Is there are mis-match with iOS?

Comment: ahh shoot... you're right Simon, I was looking at the wrong docs. :)  let me edit and fix this comment.

Comment: I am also doing the same thing but it still doesn't work.I checked with both 'uri' and 'origin'.I entered the entire url itself in config.xml,still it doesn't download.It gives the same message everytime- "Source URL is not in white list: 'http://www.myurl.whatever'"

Comment: @PrasadW Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wild card in the whitelist URL configuration, don't use subdomain property.

Looks like you have to be very specific in how you write the tags in config.xml especially when it comes to allowing subdomains - apparently specifying subdomains does not work with wildcards so you need two blocks of tags.

```
<access origin="*.google.com" />
<access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="*.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="*.googleusercontent.com" />
<access origin="google.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="googleusercontent.com" subdomains="true"/>
```