# Whitelist FileTransfer Problems

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using this code to download a file to an android device using the FileTransfer plugin

```
function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
    alert(fp);
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    // File download function with URL and local path
    fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
    function (entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function (error) {
    //Download abort errors or download failed errors
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
    //alert("download error target " + error.target);
    //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
   );
}
```

The transfer fails. I checked my configuration, which is set to accept from all domains. I have the project > res > xml > config.xml with `<access origin="*"/>`

why is this not working?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? app crash or not? show some logcat about your question

Comment: It gives Source URL is not in whitelist. 
And show the error alert

Comment: did you already read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023185/phonegap-source-url-is-not-in-whitelist) ?

Comment: Yes I've been looking for hours, as I said I already have <access origin="*" /> in my config.xml file

Comment: Does the lines order matter in the config.xml file for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using cordova-android version 4.0, I you will need the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). With the 5.0 version release of the cordova cli, the core plugin updates have some breaking changes.

[Cordova Blog: Moving Plugins to NPM](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html)

> We recently released cordova-plugin-whitelist and
>   cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist. We have revamped how whitelisting
>   works starting with cordova-android@4.0.0. With this change, setting a
>   Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported. Network requests are
>   blocked by default without cordova-plugin-whitelist, so install this
>   plugin even to allow all requests, and even if you are using CSP.

Also be aware of the change in Plugin IDs with this move to npm (e.g. `org.apache.cordova.file-transfer` to `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`) which could trip you up as you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Pass true for the `trustAllHosts` parameter.

```
function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(
        download_link, 
        fp,
        function (entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
        }, 
        true //trust all hosts (defaults to false)
   );
}
```

> trustAllHosts: Optional parameter, defaults to false. If set to true,
>   it accepts all security certificates. This is useful since Android
>   rejects self-signed security certificates. Not recommended for
>   production use. Supported on Android and iOS. (boolean)

Source: [File-Transfer Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

Comment: Doesn't do it for me. I have the same problem as @user3582378

Comment: If you're using android version 4.0, I think you will need the whitelist plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Thank you very much! You should ad this as an answer! :-D